# Rails always using production environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm having an issue where no matter what environment I try to run Rails in it always goes to production.  For example:

```
$ rails c development
Loading production environment (Rails 3.2.16)
1.9.3p484 :001 > 

$ RAILS_ENV=development rails console
Loading production environment (Rails 3.2.16)
1.9.3p484 :001 >
```

I first noticed this when I was running the Rails server and it was writing to the production database instead of development.  If I run "rails s -e development" it says it starts up in development but still uses the production database.

Here's my config/environment.rb

```
# Load the rails application
require File.expand_path('../application', __FILE__)

# Initialize the rails application
Skeletor::Application.initialize!
```

I tried grepping through the project to see if RAILS_ENV was being set anywhere but I don't see it.

Comment: What does your database.yml file look like?

Comment: What is the output of running `env` in bash/zsh/etc?

Comment: What is the value of Rails.env in console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In an initializer I had done "if Rails.env = 'production'" instead of "if Rails.env == 'production'" which was causing the problem.  Thanks for the suggestions everyone, I knew it had to be something silly.

Answer (score 0):

Try run:

```
RAILS_ENV=development bundle exec rails s
```